# How to convert video files using settings from ffprobe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert a video file **.mp4** to **.avi** using the setting of an .avi file that works for me on my DVD player. I used `ffprobe` to see the settings of the working .avi file and here it is:

```
Duration: 01:38:21.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2031 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 720x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
```

How can I use the settings above with `ffmpeg` to convert my .mp4 file?

Answer (score 0):

This will require some experimentation. Start simple and then add more options until it works:

#### Simple

```
ffmpeg -i input output.avi
```

#### Complex

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v mpeg4 -vf scale=720:-1 -profile:v 15 -tag:v DX50 -r 25 \
-q:v 4 -c:a ac3 -ar 48000 -ac 6 output.avi
```

#### Notes

- Some of these options will be unnecessary and possibly detrimental (such as setting frame rate with `-r`), but some devices are very picky.
- You can add the `-t 60` option to encode a 60 second section for testing.
- Got to the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to recent builds. Don't use an ancient `ffmpeg`.